# Don't know cause for 9px margin between elements

Tags: html, css, margin

Sorry for me being a total noob but I want to start a website and I heard that I should use margin 0 auto to center the layout. I've searched everywhere for this but I don't think it's the same issue as here.

CSS:

```
#page-wrap
{
    height: 1008px;
    width: 900px;
    background: #000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="page-wrap"></div>
    <header></header>
</body>
```

I am getting an unexplained 9px margin between the top of the window and the #page-wrap div.

http://gyazo.com/90fe8fe2e151ac9ae5b0bc93d3b5ba79.png

Please explain what I'm doing wrong and don't laugh im ultra newbie.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

`margin: 0 auto;` applies 0 margin to the top of the element and `auto` margins to the right of the element.

With CSS margins the values are applied to element clockwise from the top so:

```
margin: 10px 11px 12px 13px;
```

applies margins in the following way

```
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 11px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
margin-left: 13px;
```

the 9px margin is caused by the browsers default padding. You can override the browser default styles like so:

```
body, html
{
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
{

#page-wrap
{
    height: 1008px;
    width: 930px;
    background: #000000;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: See edits - you need to override the browsers auotmatically added styling

Comment: you're welcome, if you wouldnt mind accepting the answer I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Try this by adding to your css with global selector *

```
{ margin:0px; padding:0px;}
```